# Apache2 Rewrite Problems

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, apache2, ubuntu-20.04

I have the Problem that i tryed to host a Web Application which requires Rewrite Enabled but everything i did try ended in the situation that the Main Page (Startpage) does work but clicking then like the
information button or just something which redirects, i get a URL NOT FOUND 404 error

I did try to enable apache2 rewrite with a2enmod rewrite but already enabled

I also checked the apache2 config file and did set to every single point AllowOverride from none to all and restarted apache but still dont work

Also checked if some Directory Parameters are under site available but there are nones

**UPDATE:** Contents of `.htaccess`:

```
<ifmodule mod_mime.c>
    AddType application/x-web-app-manifest+json .webapp
    Addtype font/truetype .ttf
</ifmodule>
 
<ifmodule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType image/svg+xml "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType font/truetype "access plus 1 week"
</ifmodule>
 
FileETag None
 
<ifmodule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
</ifmodule>
 
<ifmodule mod_filter.c>
    <IfModule mod_deflate.c>
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css text/html application/javascript font/truetype
    </IfModule>
</ifmodule>
 
<ifmodule mod_headers.c>
    Header set X-Frame-Options DENY
    Header set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff
    Header set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
    Header set Referrer-Policy no-referrer
</ifmodule>
```

Comment: "set to every single point AllowOverride from none to all" - You should **not** change all "None" values to "All", that could potentially result in a security vulnerability and will certainly result in additional (unnecessary) overhead. You would likely need to create a specific `<Directory>` container in the relevant `<VirtualHost>` for the directory in question (the DocumentRoot I assume). Are you editing the correct config for your site? Is the `.htaccess` enabled, but the directives are not correct?

Comment: There could be any number of reasons why this is not working, unfortunately, there's not a lot to go on here.

Comment: So security Risk isnt a thing because its a local app, not public reachable. Second im sure i edited the right config, i also try to add the Directory which is var/www/html to the relevant virtual host but dosnt work either. I can post the .htaccess in a few mins it should be enabeld

Comment: If you write some garbage at the top of the `.htaccess` file, do you get an error? (You should get a 500 Internal Server Error - if not then the `.htaccess` overrides for that directory are _not_ enabled.) And, I assume you are restarting Apache after making changes to the server config?

Comment: yes i restarted multiple times of course

Comment: yep it does kick me out an internal server error if i do write some bs in

Comment: Content of htaccess: `https://pastebin.com/myADmP23`

Comment: Remove the `<ifmodule mod_rewrite.c>` wrapper (you shouldn't use it anyway) - any errors? "the Main Page (Startpage) does work" - this doesn't require mod_rewrite since mod_dir will otherwise serve `index.php` when requesting the directory.